# Python 3.4 не работает код

Tags: python

При открытии - черное окошко на секунду и все.

Вот код:

```
name = input("Как вас зовут? ")
print("Привет,", name)
```

Comment: В какой способ вы запускаете код, и какое расширение имеет ваш python-файл?

Comment: Запускаю через консоль , расширение .py

Answer (score 3):

Программа закрывается потому что она у вас она выполнилась. Попробуйте вот так чтобы после выполнения она не закрывалась сразу, а закрывалась после нажатия любой кнопки

```
name = input("Как вас зовут? ")
print("Привет,", name)
input('Press any key')
```

Comment: Из вопроса следует, что программа даже не ждёт первого ввода.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: @КириллМалышев ну раз это [помогло](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773365/python-3-4-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4#comment1208362_773368) значит проблема в формулировке вопроса